# Call a Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2010

I have connected to a Web service by adding it as a web reference,
the wsdl and xsd files are now visable,
im using visual studio,

How can I get a response from the Web service,
i.e. send some data and get an error message back.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: please fix your title (Serice should be Service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you add a web service reference, Visual Studio will generate a strongly typed client proxy class which you could instantiate and invoke the web method:

```
using (var proxy = new SomeClientProxy())
{
    var result = proxy.SomeMethod("foo", "bar");
}
```

Comment: I see, how can I locate the client proxy?

Comment: It is generated by Visual Studio. Try importing the namespace you used in the Add Web Service Reference dialog.

Comment: would this be in the dfault aspx page?

Comment: @Lambo, no it won't be in the default.aspx page. It will be in the generated web reference. Right click on it and Show Code.

Answer (score 0):

Just Create the object and use its method as you normally do with regular class objects

1- YourWebService obj = new YourWebService();

2- call methods on this object.

obj.YourWebServiceMethod();

Comment: could you give me an example of how that would be displayed in code please?